# How to get number of active rules in Drools?

Tags: java, drools

I am using Drools' decision table mechanism for generating rules.

How can I determine the number of rules that were generated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int nRules = 0;
Collection<KiePackage> packages = kieBase.getKiePackages();
for( KiePackage pack: packages ){
    nRules += pack.getRules().size();
}
```

You can also count the rows below the header lines in your decision table: one row - one rule.